# Where is the Text of Product Description Stored in Prestashop Database

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

I am working on building a database for online shop using Microsoft SQL Server. I downloaded Prestashop and installed it on my machine. I am working out its database which seems very complicated.

What stopped me is when I view the product table in Prestashop as admin, I can see text description of each item. But when I view it in the MySQL database I can't see it!!! (I am using XAMPP to view the database) I mean there's no column called description or something. Any one knows where they hide the text?

Comment: Is there any join column that might point to another table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In PrestaShop, the texts are saved to database in tables that have their names ending in `_lang`, in your case it is `ps_product_lang` (`ps_` is default prefix). This allows the relation to `to many` as a text can be in more than one language.

Comment: Thank you Zimmi.
Do you know which column in ps_product table refers to the text? Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. In `ps_product` it is the `id_product` column that is referenced by the column of same name in the table `ps_product_lang`. In the table `ps_product_lang`. All columns in `ps_product_lang` that do not make the primary key  (3 columns) relate to language and contain texts. For product description there are 2 columns : `description`and `description_short`. If you do not known about this structure, search for `one to many relationship in relational databases`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense now